# NSUndoManager does not seem to post NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification on undo or redo

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsundomanager

My app performs certain actions in a method attached to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification (which is being executed on save). It also uses an `NSUndoManager` which is undoing/redoing happily. I had expected the 'did save' notification to be raised whenever an undo or redo occurred (in cases where the undo/redo affected the Core Data repository), but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Is it reasonable to expect the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to be posted for undo/redo? If not, is there a way we can determine what was undone/redone after the fact (`NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification` does not appear to expose that info)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was mistaken in my assumption that undo/redo should have anything to do with saving the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Because my app auto-saves, my beleaguered brain thought that the undo/redo would auto-save too. Clearly this is not so.

I'm now observing the `NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification` and `NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification` notifications and manually saving there which is (currently) giving me the behaviour I expect.